Внутри сети softether vpn windows сервера не получается достучаться до raspberry pi (клиента подключенного к серверу)
Было настроено подключение клиента softether vpn на rpi. На rpi клиенте установлен openwebrx (websdr) морда на порте 8073. Сервер с windows server и softether vpn server с проброшенным портом 8073. На rpi было сделано: /etc/sysctl.conf параметр: net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 ; Был получен ipv4 для клиентского виртуального адаптера при помощи dhcp на стороне сервера. Этот адрес был присвоен vpn_vpn адаптеру 192.168.1.85. На rpi  openwebrx локально размещается (веб морда) на 127.0.0.1 с доменом локальным openwebrx. Порты при помощи iptables открыты. Как маршутизировать веб морду на ip 192.168.1.85, выданный впн сервером, чтобы можно было внутри впн сети достучаться до rpi. Все это сделано для обхода черного ip провайдера.
